# Cordova File write not working in ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to create a file and download it device directory.i have followed [this](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file) tutorial to write file using cordova file plugin.I am getting success console but i cant find the file in device directory.But its perfectly working in android.Not working in ios device.

Here is my code

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.documentsDirectory, function(dir) {
        console.log("got main dir",dir);
        dir.getFile("log.txt", {create:true}, function(file) {
            console.log("got the file", file);
            logOb = file;
             if(!logOb) return;
    var log = "App started" + " [" + (new Date()) + "]\n";
    console.log("going to log "+log);
    logOb.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);

        var blob = new Blob([log], {type:'text/plain'});
        fileWriter.write(blob);
        console.log("success");
    }, false);        
        });
    });
```

Config file permissions

```
 <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Documents" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />

<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
</feature>
<feature name="File">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
</feature>
```

Can anyone helpme?

Comment: You say you can't "find" the file - how are you trying to find it? Show the code where you read it and share the error message you get with iOS but not Android.

Comment: @RaymondCamden I am getting "success" console message like android.So there is no error message.I am searching downloaded file using some filemanager app in iphone.Thanks

Comment: did you finally find where is the file, im facing the same error